# LSTM - train the model given vector as an input feature

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am training a model in LSTM to forecast a single step based on input vector. Here is the sample data:

[image]

My input is Phrase sequence (vector) and my goal is to predict 'Cost'. The reason Phrase sequence is a vector is because I have multiple records on the same date.
I have successfully splitted the data with the following shape:

```
x_train: (249, 7) y_train: (249,)
x_val: (2, 7) y_val: (2,)
```

Now when I pass this input to Keras, it gives me following error:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert numpy ndarray to a Tensor (Unable to get element as bytes.).
```

I have used following code to split and shape my data:

```
def multivariate_data(dataset, target, start_index, end_index, history_size,
                      target_size, step, single_step=False):
  data = []
  labels = []

  start_index = start_index + history_size
  if end_index is None:
    end_index = len(dataset) - target_size

  for i in range(start_index, end_index):
    indices = range(i-history_size, i, step)
    data.append(dataset[indices])

    if single_step:
      labels.append(target[i+target_size])
    else:
      labels.append(target[i:i+target_size])

  return np.array(data), np.array(labels)
```

I have followed [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#single_step_model) tutorial. Here is my code:

```
train_data_single = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train_single, y_train_single))
train_data_single = train_data_single.cache().shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE).repeat()

val_data_single = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val_single, y_val_single))
val_data_single = val_data_single.batch(BATCH_SIZE).repeat()

single_step_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
single_step_model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32,input_shape=x_train_single.shape[-2:]))
single_step_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
single_step_model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer=tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001))
```

How do I convert numpy nd array to a Tensor?

Answer (score 0):

Try eliminating lists from Phrase_sequence by padding. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding